# Nested delimiter problem with gawk/sed

Tags: sed, awk, gawk

I've this text that I need to split:

```
[{names: {en: 'UK 100', es: 'UK 100'}, status: 'A', displayed: 'Y', start_time: '2011-05-12 00:00:00', start_time_xls: {en: '12th of May 2011  00:00 am', es: '12 May 2011 00:00 am'}, suspend_at: '2011-05-12 15:14:02', is_off: 'Y', score_home: '', score_away: '', bids_status: '', period_id: '', curr_period_start_time: '', score_extra_info: '', settled: 'N', ev_id: 2666872, ev_type_id: 10744, type_name: '|UK 100|'}, {names: {en: 'US 30', es: 'US 30'}, status: 'A', displayed: 'Y', start_time: '2011-05-12 00:00:00', start_time_xls: {en: '12th of May 2011  00:00 am', es: '12 May 2011 00:00 am'}, suspend_at: '2011-05-12 15:13:45', is_off: 'Y', score_home: '', score_away: '', bids_status: '', period_id: '', curr_period_start_time: '', score_extra_info: '', settled: 'N', ev_id: 2666879, ev_type_id: 10745, type_name: '|US 30|'}, {names: {en: 'Germany 30', es: 'Germany 30'}, status: 'A', displayed: 'Y', start_time: '2011-05-12 00:00:00', start_time_xls: {en: '12th of May 2011  00:00 am', es: '12 May 2011 00:00 am'}, suspend_at: '2011-05-12 15:13:52', is_off: 'Y', score_home: '', score_away: '', bids_status: '', period_id: '', curr_period_start_time: '', score_extra_info: '', settled: 'N', ev_id: 2666884, ev_type_id: 10748, type_name: '|Germany 30|'}, {names: {en: 'France 40', es: 'France 40'}, status: 'A', displayed: 'Y', start_time: '2011-05-12 00:00:00', start_time_xls: {en: '12th of May 2011  00:00 am', es: '12 May 2011 00:00 am'}, suspend_at: '2011-05-12 15:13:38', is_off: 'Y', score_home: '', score_away: '', bids_status: '', period_id: '', curr_period_start_time: '', score_extra_info: '', settled: 'N', ev_id: 2666882, ev_type_id: 10747, type_name: '|France 40|'}, {names: {en: 'US 500', es: 'US 500'}, status: 'A', displayed: 'Y', start_time: '2011-05-12 00:00:00', start_time_xls: {en: '12th of May 2011  00:00 am', es: '12 May 2011 00:00 am'}, suspend_at: '2011-05-12 15:14:30', is_off: 'Y', score_home: '', score_away: '', bids_status: '', period_id: '', curr_period_start_time: '', score_extra_info: '', settled: 'N', ev_id: 2666890, ev_type_id: 10749, type_name: '|US 500|'}, {names: {en: 'Spain 35', es: 'Spain 35'}, status: 'A', displayed: 'Y', start_time: '2011-05-12 00:00:00', start_time_xls: {en: '12th of May 2011  00:00 am', es: '12 May 2011 00:00 am'}, suspend_at: '2011-05-12 15:13:51', is_off: 'Y', score_home: '', score_away: '', bids_status: '', period_id: '', curr_period_start_time: '', score_extra_info: '', settled: 'N', ev_id: 2666886, ev_type_id: 10750, type_name: '|Spain 35|'}],
```

I've tried variants of these, but keep getting caught by the 'inner' delimiters that I DON'T want to split!!:

gawk -F "["   -v RS="," "NF{print $0}" text.txt

How can I split them (1) First on the main "{", ignoring the inner "{"'s (2) Then on the commas, ignoring commas in between curly braces. I then want to output only one or two fields like this:

suspend_at: '2011-05-12 15:14:02', ev_id: 2666872, ev_type_id: 10744, type_name: '|UK 100|'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What a nightmare. Comma delimited data consider harmful! Do the square brackets really offer any value? If not sed them out first, sed out any chars that don't help. Otherwise that looks like a real project. Use the unix pipelines to iteratively clean down the data until you have something you can feed to a printf statement. OR post this as a perl problem. Good luck.

Comment: Also, is this really one big long line of data? I measure ~2500 chars. Can't it be broken up into numerous lines? That will greatly simplify the task. Good luck.

Comment: You really need a language with a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, if Perl is acceptable:

```
% perl -MText::ParseWords -nle'
   /suspend|ev_(id|type)|type_name/ and print for parse_line("[{},]",0, $_);
  ' infile
 suspend_at: 2011-05-12 15:14:02
 ev_id: 2666872
 ev_type_id: 10744
 type_name: |UK 100|
 suspend_at: 2011-05-12 15:13:45
 ev_id: 2666879
 ev_type_id: 10745
 type_name: |US 30|
 suspend_at: 2011-05-12 15:13:52
 ev_id: 2666884
 ev_type_id: 10748
 type_name: |Germany 30|
 suspend_at: 2011-05-12 15:13:38
 ev_id: 2666882
 ev_type_id: 10747
 type_name: |France 40|
 suspend_at: 2011-05-12 15:14:30
 ev_id: 2666890
 ev_type_id: 10749
 type_name: |US 500|
 suspend_at: 2011-05-12 15:13:51
 ev_id: 2666886
 ev_type_id: 10750
 type_name: |Spain 35|
```